# How to migrate data to new database in windows phone 8 application development?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have searched in msdn site but no sample is available...can u please tell how to do migration?``

Comment: what database? usually this is done via a SQL-DUMP or a programm syncing databases via a database link

Comment: in windows phone 8 application development,database stored in isolated storage...but if i want to change column name,in msdn it is given that we have to migrate database to new database...so i want to do that..sqlce i have used for creating database